# simple wildcard match with std::string

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have std::string with the follwing format

```
std::string s = "some string with @lable"
```

I have to find all instances of '@'  and then find the  identifier  right after the '@' ,
this ID has a value (in this case 'lable'  stored for it in a look up table. I will then replace  the @ and the id with the found value.

for example suppose the ID label has the value '1000'  after the process the string will look like :

```
"some string with 1000"
```

my first version used boost::regex,  but I had to dump it after I was told that  new libs are not allowed in the next few builds.

so is there some elegant way to do it with vanilla std::string and std algorithms ?

Comment: You're not allowed to use a new library but you're allowed to write your own new library?

Comment: yap thats my life in dilbert world ;(

Comment: I think this is the sort of case where regex would actually be an overkill.  It's slower and with Boost I don't even think you'd save on loc or complexity in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `std::find` to search for the `@`, and get a pair of iterators forming a range which begins at the `@` and ends at the next white space character (or end of the string).  Then just pass the iterators to `std::string::replace()` to do the actual sub-string replacement.

For example:

```
std::string s = "some string with @lable";
std::string::iterator beg = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '@');
std::string::iterator end = std::find(beg, s.end(), ' ');
s.replace(beg, end, "whatever");
```

If you also want to count things like tabs or carriage returns as spaces, you can use `std::find_if` along with `::isspace`.

Comment: Don't forget to check that you actually found something to replace. you didn't mention the constraints on your inputs, if there could be more than one occurrence of an ID in a string, if one must always be present etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. use std::find to search for @, and then std::find to search for space, and copy everything in between aside.